# Javascript: Can anyone explain me this block of code?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

i dont understand this two functions down below. They use an argument that is a function (done) and then they call the function inside of that function? Please tell me what type of function is this and how it works. Thank you!

```
beforeEach((done) => {
    Todo.remove({}).then(() => done());
});

describe('POST /todos', () => {
    it('should creat a new todo', (done) => {
        var text = 'Test todo text';

        request(app)
            .post('/todos')
            .send({text})
            .expect(200)
            .expect((res) => {
                expect(res.body.text).toBe(text);
            })
            .end((err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err);
                }

                Todo.find().then((todos) => {
                    expect(todos.length).toBe(1);
                    expect(todos[0].text).toBe(text);
                    done();
                }).catch((e) => done(e));
            })
    })
});
```

Comment: There is no way to explain it as we do not know what the non-native functions are and/or do, what framework is used, if any, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

> Please tell me what type of function is this

The regular kind.

> and how it works.

Functions in JS are first class objects. You can pass them about like any other value.

```js
function a_function() {
  alert("This is a function");
}

function give_me_a_callback(some_function) {
  some_function();
}

give_me_a_callback(a_function);
```